# MongoDB search preference

Tags: mongodb

I wonder, does the order of conditions in $or query matter?

E.g. can this query be reliable to get either document where role matches `userrole` or any other document **only** if the one with `userrole` is not found?

```
{$or: [{role: 'userrole'},{}]}, {limit: 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Order does not matter.**

Since the operator `$or$` gets evaluated document-wise, the query

```
{$or: [{role: 'userrole'},{}]}
```

will evaluate to `true` on each document, hence it will always return **every** document in the collection.

If, in addition, you use the `limit()` method, then the first `n` documents in the collection (according to their internal ordering) will be returned.